# Javascript - Possible to use a shorthand conditional within an HTML variable declaration?

Tags: javascript

I am building an HTML element based on some JSON data. I would like to add a class to one element or the other based on a conditional variable, here's what I tried:

```js
$(function() {
  var lorem = true;

  var html = '<div>' +
              '<span class="ele ' + (lorem) ? 'green' : '' +  '">Lorem</span>' + 
              '<span class="ele ' + (lorem) ? '' : 'green' +  '">Ipsum</span>' +
             '</div>';

  $('.container').html(html);
});
```

```css
.green {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

In this example I want class `green` to be added to the first `span`, but instead it appears to just be replacing the entire HTML with the word `green`. I know that I could just set up the entire HTML variable within the conditional statement, but the HTML is going to end up being a lot of code so I would prefer not to do it that way if possible.

Comment: You have to parenthesize the entire `? :` group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap the ternary statement in parenthesis, it will do as you are looking.

```js
$(function() {
  var lorem = true;

  var html = '<div>' +
              '<span class="ele ' + ((lorem) ? 'green' : '') +  '">Lorem</span>' + 
              '<span class="ele ' + ((lorem) ? '' : 'green') +  '">Ipsum</span>' +
             '</div>';

  $('.container').html(html);
});
```

```css
.green {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot parentheses, please see updated code.

I've also added a version with es6 multiline strings.

```js
$(function() {
  var lorem = true;

  var html = '<div>' +
          '<span class="ele ' + ((lorem) ? 'green' : '') +  '">Lorem</span>' + 
          '<span class="ele ' + ((lorem) ? '' : 'green') +  '">Ipsum</span>' +
         '</div>';

  var html2 = `<div>
              <span class="ele ${lorem ? 'green' : ''}">Lorem2</span> 
              <span class="ele ${lorem ? '' : 'green'}">Ipsum2</span>
             </div>`;


  $('.container').html(html + '<br/>' + html2);
});
```

```css
.green {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when building statements like this. Try to execute the following in the console:

```
'test' + (true) ? 'green' : ''
```

Your expectation is that this will end up being `testgreen`. However this is not what logically is happening.

When the interpreter is running this code it first executes only the `'test' + (true)` part. The result of it is:

```
'test' + (true) => 'testtrue'
```

After that the rest of the statement is executed which right now is:

```
'testtrue' ? 'green' : ''
```

The `testtrue` is always evaluated to `true` so this is equivalent to calling `true ? 'green' : ''` which ends up being just `green`.